# How to modify a CSS value when it's nested?

Tags: javascript, css

I can change the top property of percent1 with

```
document.getElementById('percent1').style.top = '50px';
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box" id="box1">
  <div class="percent" id="percent1">
   <svg>
      <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
      <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
    </svg>
    <div class="num">
      <h2>45<span>%</span></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="text">Percentage</h2>
</div>
```

CSS to modify:

```
.box .percent svg circle:nth-child(2)
{
  stroke-dashoffset:calc(440 - (440 * 15) / 100);
}
```

How can I change "stroke-dashoffset" value when it's nested like this?

Comment: Using JS? Consider using a css custom property? https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-custom-properties/

Comment: I'm looking to use JS/JQuery, but I don't know what it's called when it has more details like this. I just know how to modify the CSS property when it's simple. I'm looking at the link now, thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. `document.querySelectorAll(".box .percent svg circle:nth-child(2)")`?

Comment: Yea I'm not quite sure I understand the question, you just want to change that `stroke-dashoffset` from 374 to something else?

Comment: How is the CSS value nested?

Comment: Yes "stroke-dashoffset" is the value I want to change.

Comment: Then you want to use `document.querySelector('.box .percent svg circle:nth-child(2)').style.stroke-dashoffset = 123`, there is nothing nested. It's just a different property name that has a dash in it

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense! I didn't use querySelector before so I couldn't figure out how to get this particular element.

Comment: @rook218 Yes but stroke-dashoffset should be strokeDashoffset.

Comment: document.querySelector('.box .percent svg circle:nth-child(2)').style['stroke-dashoffset'] worked for me. Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear `:nth-child` [targeting matches elements based upon their position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), not on their properties so I think what you want isn't possible with this approach.

Could consider attaching some other type of targeting mechanism (either in HTML or JS) to target the element you want to style more granularly in CSS.

```css
#percent1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

#percent1>svg {
  overflow: visible;
}

#percent1>svg>circle {
  fill: blue;
}

#percent1>svg>circle:nth-child(2) {
  fill: yellow;
}

#circle-target {
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1">
  <div class="percent" id="percent1">
    <svg>
      <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
      <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70" id="circle-target"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".box .percent svg circle:nth-child(2)")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from answering questions with just a code snippet. [Check this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write an answer.